Is there a way to use the output data from a function and pass it back to the function repeatedly until a stopping point?
For example, I have a dynamic url that changes its response when the id parameter is changed. Under every id given, a name is given and the next-id for that id parameter is given. I want to save each name under an array for later, whilst going through the journey of using the next-id for the id parameter in the url each time. I did notice the response for an id does eventually change with more or less data. I want to stop the repetition until that change happens only when the next-id data is no longer in the response, then log the array showing all the names from the responses.
const array = [];
var randomNumber = '2'; //lets give it '2'

async function get(id) {
    await page.goto(`https://names.com/id=${id}`);
    var html = page.content(); //response html is like: next-id="43", name="john"...
    var nextId = html.match(/next-id="(.*?)"/)[1]; //get the id '43' from html response
    var name = html.match(/name="(.*?)"/)[1]; //get the name 'john' from html response
    array.push(name); //save the name 'john' into an array

    try {
        get(nextId); //repeat everything under the same condition but use the new '43' instead of the original '2' to retrieve new data...
    } catch {
        return; //until the response under the next requested 'id' is missing the data 'next-id' in the response 
    }
}

get(randomNumber);
console.log(array); //log the entire list of names.

I wanted to try a For Loop or something but I am just too new to this that I cannot comprehend how to write that. I thought functions would be a good way until everything just fell apart.
